# Control a request when a jQuery Ajax call done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm using `$.post()` to call a server using Ajax and then using the `JTemplate` to write data to the current page. However, if the session times out, the server sends a redirect directive to send the user to the login page. In this case, `jQuery` is replacing the `div` element with the contents of the login page, forcing the user's eyes to witness a rare scene indeed.

How can I manage a redirect directive from an `Ajax` call with `jQuery 1.9`?

Comment: Have you tried to catch that exception in "error" block of $.post() settings ?

Answer (score 1):

You must use json data to response to client. 
For example:
In PHP file

```
<?php
//for example, data you want to response to client is a html string
$data = '<table></table>';
if($is_timeout && $is_ajax_request) {
   //shouldn't redirect, should return json_encode
   echo json_encode(array('timeout'=>1));
   die();
}else{
   echo json_encode(array('data'=>$data));
   die();
}
```

And in your javascript `post` you can edit below:

```
$.post('your_url_to_php_file',{data:data_to_post}, function(resp){
   var data = jQuery.parseJSON(resp);
   if(data.timeout) {
      alert("timeout");
      return;
   }else{
      $("#your_div").html(data.data);
   }
})
```